# Can a use case be both an extension and an inclusion?

Tags: uml, use-case

Can a use case be both an extension and an inclusion?

[image]

Comment: Show us your *specific* use case.

Comment: Use-case diagrams in UML aren't really that useful unless you have some text. They're merely a *table of contents* of the textual use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a use case can be an extension of another use case *and* be included by a third use case as your diagram illustrates.

Extension is when a use case *extends* another use case by defining additional case logic on the parent's extension points.

Inclusion is when a use case *includes* another complete use case and can prepend or append use case logic before or after the inclusion.

Here is an example:

Let `Main UC1` be "Withdraw cash from ATM" use case for an ATM system

Let `Both Extension & Inclusion` be "Withdraw cash from out-of-network ATM". This use case defines the logic of ATM fees when the user is not a member of the ATM's bank. It *extends* the "Withdraw cash from ATM" use case.

Let `Main UC2` be "Check balance and withdraw cash from ATM". This use case describes the case where the user wants to check their balance before withdrawing cash (so they know they aren't overdrafting). This use case *includes* the "Withdraw cash from out-of-network ATM" case.

Example stolen from [What's is the difference between include and extend in use case diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696927/whats-is-the-difference-between-include-and-extend-in-use-case-diagram)